# php redirect subdomain with request url

Tags: php, string, redirect, request

I need to redirect my traffic from www.example.com/api to api.example.com/api and pass / include the request string.

Eg:

www.example.com/api?t=search&q=coffee&apikey=936043b06547843
to api.example.com/api?t=search&q=coffee&apikey=936043b06547843

each request will have a different search term and api key to pass to a subdomain of my site.

Could someone tell me what I would need to do to achieve this?

I have tried http redirect but this does not pass the string.

Comment: what have you done so far or are you not sure where to start?

Comment: I have tried changing www.example.com/api to: 

header("Location: https://api.example.com$request_uri");

but this is not passing the request to the subdomain

Answer (score 1):

Catch all the parameters you need in your old page, like so:

```
<?php
    // code
    // ...
    $t=$_GET["t"];
    // ...
    // code
?>
```

Then call `header()` accordingly to route everything to the new page, like so:

```
<?php
    // code
        header("location: api.example.com?t=$t");
    // code
?>
```

If you need everything to be passed, you can just pass the whole array through $_SESSION:

```
<?php
    // code
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["data"]=$_GET;
        header("location: api.example.com");
    // code
?>
```

And get it back like so:

```
<?php
    // code
    session_start();
    $data=$_SESSION["data"];
    session_unset();
    // code
?>
```

Of course using this last method you'll then need to access your parameters like so:

```
<?php
    // code
    $t=$data["t"];
    // code
?>
```

Comment: thankyou however this is only passing api.example.com/api?t=search 
and not including the rest of the string &q=coffee&apikey=936043b06547843

Comment: can I just define the same way?:

<?php
 $t=$_GET["t"];
 $q=$_GET["q"];
 $apikey=$_GET["apikey"];

header("location: api.example.com?t=$t&q=$q&apikey=$apikey");
 
?>

Comment: I updated my answer, the second method fits better in case you're trying to pass everything

Comment: Anyway yes, if you need only some parameter you can do it that way

Comment: I am just a little confused when you say get it back like so - Would I have the first part php code on www.example.com/api.php and the second php (and get it back like so) - on api.example.com/api.php page? or do I combine both of these parts of code on www.example.com/api.php ?

Comment: In the first part session_start() allows you to store datas into the $_SESSION array, which is a superglobal array (meaning it can be accessed from everywhere on each script), and the second part allows you to retrive the $_GET array passed through it, but since in the example your $_GET array has been stored into $data, you'll need to access what were its old parameters referencing $data instead of $_GET, therefore doing like the example in the third part. Anyway i missed something in the second part, it's not session_close() but session_unset(), and that is useful to delete the leftover data